# How do I get the game which a user is playing? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I know this question has been asked before but the accepted solutions arent solving the problem.

I have tried:

```
user.presence.activities[0];
```

and

```
user.presence.activities;
```

and

```
user.presence.activities.name;
```

and

```
user.presence.game;
```

Expected output:

```
Rainbow Six Siege
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

or

```
[] (empty array)
```

Comment: activities is an array, have you tried `activities[0].name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently started working with discord.js again and I found the cause of my problem. It was actually not the code that caused the error, but the setting of the rights that the bot has.

**To see the activities of users, you will have to turn on this:**

[image: on bot settings]

Otherwise, `user.presence.activities` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so, you were very close to finding the answer yourself, although you then, unfortunately, decided to go a different route. According to the [Discord.js documents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main), `User#presence#activities` returns an **array** of all of the active presences a user currently has, hence why right now I am saying that your first attempt was the best at getting your answer and it slowly worsened from there. Now, your only mistake in the first time is that you haven't exactly called the method for finding the name of the activity, which is as you tried later on: `Activity#name`.

Now, before I show you the code, a quick suggestion from me would be to filter out all activities who don't fall under the `Playing` type as you're currently looking to find the game a user is playing. Since `Presence#activities` returns an **array**, we can use the `find` method to find the **first** activity that falls under the `Playing` type category.

#### Final Code

```js
console.log(user.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING').name)
```

Comment: I think you can use `.find` instead of `.filter` to avoid `[0]`.

Comment: That is true, I have just edited my answer, thank you :)

Comment: I think I cant user .name because I get a TypeError that says name is undefined.

Comment: Then the spoken of user is not playing a game. According to the documents, this method will return `undefined` if the user is not playing any games at the time of this method running.